# How can I update all images in azure container registry when base image is updated

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-deployment, azure-container-registry

I have a bunch of repositories in an Azure container registry. Each repository can have several versions of an image, tagged like this, imagename:v_1_0 or imagename:v_1_2. Almost all of these images uses the base image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim.

My question is, how do I create an acr task that updates all of my images when that base image is updated by microsoft? I have seen tutorials on creating an acr task but almost all of them assume that the source code is pushed from github and that I am only updating a single image. I would like to avoid creating a task for n number of images in each repository but I suppose I could create a job that automatically creates a task whenever I publish from visual studio.

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: What is the final approach you are following to update all the images in different repositories with different tags when the base image gets updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you are building your images via ACR tasks they do that automatically for the following base images:

1. The same Azure container registry where the task runs
2. Another private Azure container registry in the same or a different region
3. A public repo in Docker Hub
4. A public repo in Microsoft Container Registry

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-base-images#base-image-notifications

if you are building them outside of ACR and pushing to ACR - you probably need to handle that in the same place you are building them. ACR cant do that for images its not building (seems fair).

Comment: I understand that, but I know you can also create a task that tracks it for existing images as well. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this for all or do I need to create a new task every time I publish a new image. Or better yet, if anyone knows how to integerate the az build command into the visual studio publish mechanism.

Comment: I found that VS code has much better azure extensions that allow me to publish with the az build command. Why the full Visual Studio enterprise doesn't have this, is beyond me.